# Change playerCharacter's facing direction in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, unityscript

I am trying (for learning purposes) to make a Portal game. I have the basics working, I can place two portals, and walking within the collider of one makes me teleport to the other, however I can't seem to get the facing direction/rotation to work.
I want to face outwards from the new portal after the teleportation.

I have tried the following, with no success:
*var angle = thisPortalCamera.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y - otherPortalCamera.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;*
*playerChar.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, angle);*

My idea here was that only the y-axis rotation really matters, and I think I should rotate the player by the difference in axis between the two portals. This is probably really simple and easy, but I am pretty new to Unity. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to set your portal so that its forward is the orientation you want you player to have. Then you just go with:

```
player.transform.rotation = portal.transform.rotation;
player.transform.position = portal.transform.position;
```

The aim is to have the blue arrow of your portal to point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way is to use the function LookAt() and Rotate() of the transform. This function take one parameter that is the Position the object has to look.

```
transform.LookAt(portal.position);
tranform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,180,0);
```

This will make your character face the opposite way of your portal.

Comment: I have now attempted both of the suggestions I got here, and I can see that they should work, but something is wrong, as the character still always faces the same direction after going through the portal as he did before.
I am using the standard FPSController character, do you know if there is any restrictions on changing the rotation (given that is controlled by mouse movements as well)

Comment: Humm do you have an animation on character where you change his orientation?

Comment: The only thing I have changed about the player character is that I have added a script for throwing portals.

Comment: Humm I have no idea then, sound like a problem with your player object but im not really sure

Comment: I have the rotation change code inside the same if statement as the position change, so it should be run, and if I change the object to be rotated to the other portal, it does rotate it.

Comment: Okok so ita really a problem with your object player

Comment: I cant really help you much on this sorry

Comment: No worries, from the thought that is an issue with the FPSController, I did a search, and found that others had similar issues, and therefore creatted their own controller object, so I guess I have to do the same if I want this thing to work, oh well. Thanks for the help!